# Is an assignment operation really returning something?

Tags: c

I am currently reading the book The C Programming Language and I need some clarifications about the following piece of code.

```
void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;
    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
    ++i;
}
```

How does the while loop work? Is the assignment returning the current element in to[i]?

Thank You in advance!

Comment: It returns whatever was assigned.  That allows things like: a = b = 0 to work.

Comment: I would not be at all surprised if it is a duplicate, but it's not exactly the same as the question that has been linked! That is asking more generally why the loop stops, including treating assignment as a boolean: this is asking for confirmation that the assignment itself has a value.

Comment: The precise term here is "expression". An expression may be evaluated to some value, and may also have other effects. For example: "5" is an expression that with quotes is usually evaluated as an string, and without quotes as an integer. Variable assignment is also an expression: "a = 2" which in languages like C is an expression than (1) assigns the number 2 to the variable a, and (2) evaluates as the number 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
```

Look at parenthesis, first from[i] is getting assigned to to[i], then result of will be compared to '\0'(0).